# Objectify não retorna query com um filtro simples

Tags: google-app-engine, google

Estou usando o Objectify 4.0.1, e não consigo fazer uma query com um filtro simples retornar valores.

Minha classe é esta:

```
@Entity
public class Jogador implements Serializable{

@Id
private Long id;

private String nome;

private String grupo;
(...)
```

Meu código tentando fazer a busca é este:

```
List <Jogador> j = ofy().load().type(Jogador.class).filter("nome", "Fernando").list();
```

A lista sempre vem vazia. Se eu retiro o filtro, todos os dados são retornados, normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

O atributo `nome` precisa estar indexado por ser usado na *query*. Para isso use a anotação `@Index` na declaração do atributo nome.